# Create a ssh user, always log in folder

Tags: linux, ssh

I want some people to have ssh access to my server, but only in a specific folder :
For example in

```
var/www/vhosts/www.mywebsite.com
```

This user should have right **in this folder** and that's all, **he cannot navigate through all the server** . But he could do thing in his folder.

I give him ip/id/password and he **directly connect to this folder** (but it's specific for this user).

Could we achieve that? 
I look at chroot jail, but it doesn't seem to be fit for me.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-one-folder-and-not-allow-them-to-move-out-his-folder

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this to give access to give ssh access to a user for a particular folder. (which is totally not recommended BTW).

```
adduser var/www/vhosts/www.mywebsite.com  --shell /bin/bash --no-create-home --ingroup www-data --ingroup ssh username
```

adduser is used to add a user

--home specifies home directory which is where the user will be when they login

--shell is to specify the shell, by default, it is usually just /bin/sh which is not as user friendly as /bin/bash

--no-create-home will not create the home directory so you must use one that already exists

--ingroup adds the user to a specified group

the last argument is the username

I recommend creating an FTP user rather than SSH user, it is totally unsafe to give shh access to the user.

Comment: If this is unsafe, what solution I have if i want people be able to link there git, create DB and modifiy code ? 
I could do that by ftp?

Comment: If you are looking to provide Webhosting solution to users, I recommend you install one of the following services, Virtualmin or vestaCP these are free to use, you can also buy Cpanel license for your server. google about each product, i think vestacp will solve all your problems.